# Как правильно записывать данные во vue.js?

Tags: yii2, vue.js

Всем привет.
На бэкенде стоит Yii 2, фронт Vue.js
НА yii 2 передаю в рендр какие то данные

```
return $this->controller->render(
        'catalog/index',
        [
            'products' => Json::encode($this->query)
        ]
    )
```

В шаблоне их вставляю в скрытый div и уже с помощью jquery принимаю их из дива и записываю в свойства объекта Vue

```
<div class="hidden" id="products"><?= $products; ?></div>

this.products = JSON.parse($('#products').text());
```

Как правильно их передавать?
Знаю, что можно записывать в объект window

```
<script>
  window['PRODUCTS'] = <?=$products?>;
</script>
created(){
  this.prodducts = window.PRODUCTS;
}
```

Но насколько это правильно?

Так же можно отдавать с Бэка json, но я не знаю точно как, буду благодарен если объясните или дадите пару подсказок/ссылок.

Знаю что это просто ужасно так делать, поэтому прошу совета.
Благодарю за ответы :)

Comment: Почему ужастно?

Comment: @RomanC ну данные передаются сначала в шаблон, а только потом в объект, мне кажется, это не совсем хорошо.
Во-вторых, можно посмотреть через html, какие данные имеются.

Comment: Почему вы думаете что это не хорошо. Хорошо или плохо понятие растяжимое.

Comment: @RomanC Возможно я не прав, но передавать данные сначала в шаблон, потом брать из шаблона, записывать в свойства, много движений.Есть же другие способы...

Answer (score 0):

Рендерите представление без передачи объектов. При инициализации Vue в mounted обращаетесь к rest контроллеру отдающему необходимые объекты.

Если необходимо  при инициализации Vue получить обязательный параметр, например
id, то можно:
1) Зарегистрировать в controller/view 
    $this->view->registerJs('var profileId="'.$profile_id.'"',View::POS_HEAD);

2) Обернуть  vue в функцию передав туда параметр.

Для того чтобы экшен отдавал json: \Yii::$app->response->format=Response::FORMAT_JSON;